# Django: ajax response doesn't show anything

Tags: python, ajax, django

In Django, I am trying to get a json using ajax. Before doing that, I will try to output a generic string instead of json. However, no matter how I try, the data does not print properly. The character "Good" in result.html  is output normally. I thought I used url incorrectly, so I tried it several ways and it did not work.

I would appreciate it if you could look at the code and let me know in detail what went wrong.

Here is my code:

**result.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello Bubble Chart</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<h1> Good</h1>
<hr>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-lastest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    //dataType: "json",
    url: "/help/",
    data: {},
    success: function(response){
        alert(data);
        $("body").append(data);
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
def json_data(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "Yes, AJAX!"
    else:
        message = "Not AJAX"
return HttpResponse(message)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^inputTest/$', views.input_V, name='input_V'),
    url(r'^inputTest/result/$', views.result, name='result'),
    url(r'^inputTest/process/$', views.process, name='process'),
    url(r'^inputTest/help/', views.json_data, name='json_data'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Try to change `url: "/help/",` into `url: "{% url 'json_data' %}",`

Comment: see in console what the request says.

Comment: Actually, `url: "/help/"` equals `url: "{% url 'json_data' %}"`. Thanks to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your view should be like this,

```
def json_data(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "Yes, AJAX!"
    else:
        message = "Not AJAX"
    return JsonResponse(dict(message, message))
```

Also, your ajax request should be,

If you are on the result view,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/help/",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
        $("body").append(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I checked console and 'csrf_token' was the problem. When I solved that problem, It works very well.  Thanks to help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to fix is the typo in the URL of the jquery CDN - it should be:

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
```

not

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-lastest.min.js
```

i.e. `...latest...` not `...lastest...`.

Without jquery the ajax call has no chance of working.

Comment: I'm very mistake... :< Thanks to help me.